# Search query in python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm attempting to complete an assignment where I need to create a search bar that when a user inputs an isbn, author, or title, it returns results based off of a data table with book information. It should account for partial matches. Using python, postgresql (Heroku), flask, jinja.

I'm brand new to python so I've tried everything I've researched so far. I think the error is in my html file but can't quite figure out where the issue is or how to fix it. When I put something in the search bar, I'm taking to results.html but all that prints is the  line.

Python

```
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():

 if request.method == 'POST':

    search=request.form.get("search")

    results=db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE ('%' || 
    :search || '%') or  author LIKE ('%' || :search || '%') or title 
    LIKE ('%' || :search || '%')",{"search":search})


    return render_template("results.html", search=results)
    else:
    return redirect("search.html")
```

results.html (where I think the problem is):

```
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block body %}

    <h3> RESULTS </h3>


    <ul>
    {% for results in books %}
     <li> <a href = "{{url_for('search', title = search.title)}}"> 
          {{search.title}}, {{search.author}}</a> </li>
  {% endfor %}
    </ul>


   {% endblock %}
```

This should return a list of results based on the query and what matches in the database. For reference, my table has the following columns (isbn, title, author, year).

Comment: Assuming that you use `psycopg2` as driver, your `results` varibale is `None`; `execute` on a cursor does not return a result. You'll have to use sth. along the lines of `results = db.fetchall()` after the call to `execute`. What is `books` that you iterate over in your template?

Comment: @shmee thanks for the input. I changed my template to {% for result in results %} and I changed my return to ("results.html", results=results). I also updated the {{}} in template to results.isbn etc. That seemed to kind of work. It printed the strings in my template but not the data in {{}}. I did what you said and added results=db.fetchall() after db.execute and got an Attribution error. So I added it to the end of db.execute().fetchall() and I was able to get to my results.html but no data is printing still. Just strings.

Comment: Is this app using `flask_sqlalchemy` as well? I.e. is `db` a scoped SQLAlchemy session? In that case, you actually don't need the `fetchall()`; your previous code was correct. But that information should have been part of your question ;)